# Resize text and change position of different arrays from multiple excel sheets in VBA to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, position, powerpoint, dimensions

I am fairly new at this but am beating my head on this.  I have a basic functioning code where it opens up the PP and inputs the data from my excel sheets.  But it auto centers each sheet's array and the text looks very small.  I want to be able to basically make the text larger on different scales, and reposition a couple arrays on each sheet as I see fit. I know the "populate our arrays" is kind of truncated, so I would assume I would need to break that apart to apply the custom dimensions to each sheet.  Thank you so much in advance.

```
Sub ExportMultipleRangeToPowerPoint_Method1()

    'Declare PowerPoint Variables
    Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    
    'Opens a new PowerPoint presentation based on template and pastes data into Slide 2 of Powerpoint from Excel
    Dim PPapp As PowerPoint.Application, PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPslide As PowerPoint.Slide, PPShape As Object
    Dim XLws As Worksheet
  
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    Dim RngArray As Variant
    Dim ShtArray As Variant
    
    'Populate our arrays
    RngArray = Array("A1:E16", "C2:E6", "B2:D6")
    ShtArray = Array("Summary", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True
    
    'Create a new Presentation
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    
    'Loop through the range array, create a slide for each range, and copy that range on to the slide.
    For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)
    
        'Set a reference to the range
        Set ExcRng = Worksheets(ShtArray(x)).Range(RngArray(x))

        'Copy the range
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Create a new Slide
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
        
        'Paste the range in the slide
        PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste

        
    Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
    ' width, height, left, top
    ImgArray = Array("300,300,100,100", _
                     "200,200,200,200", _
                     "150,150,150,150")
    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        PPTApp.Visible = True
    
    'Create a new Presentation
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add
    
    'Loop through the range array, create a slide for each range, and copy that range on to the slide.
    Dim x
    For x = LBound(RngArray) To UBound(RngArray)
    
        'Set a reference to the range
        Set ExcRng = Worksheets(ShtArray(x)).Range(RngArray(x))

        'Copy the range
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Create a new Slide
        Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(x + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
        
        'Paste the range in the slide
        ar = Split(ImgArray(x), ",")
        With PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)
            .Width = ar(0)
            .Height = ar(1)
            .Left = ar(2)
            .Top = ar(3)
        End With
  
    Next x
```